# Redacting secrets in GitHub actions logs for text that is not stored in official action secrets

Tags: github-actions

Github action workflows automatically redact text in output logs which matches any secrets stored in the relevant action secrets. This works fine for simple cases.

However, I use AWS SSM for storing secrets (for a variety of reasons) - and there are cases where I want to populate the environment for a given step with values from SSM. Unfortunately, actions automatically log the entire environment for every step. Since these secrets aren't official action secrets, GH is unaware that they're sensitive and happily logs them (less happily for me). GH also logs arguments sent to any action step - and many actions require sensitive variables and tokens as arguments.

Is there a way to do this or are GitHub actions essentially unusable if you aren't using their secrets solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [Mask a value in log](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-log)

Here is a simple example, where you mask the value in an environment variable, but it can be done with any value:

```
MY_NAME="Mona The Octocat"
echo "::add-mask::$MY_NAME"
```

This will tell GitHub whenever you see this value in the output, mask it with `***`

If you are implementing an action yourself and use JavaScript in the [toolkit/core](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#setting-a-secret) there is a function to mask logs.

```
core.setSecret('myPassword');
```